# What does it mean to "convey X physical damage over Y seconds"?

Tags: torchlight-2

Using context clues, one can assume that, in this instance, convey means "deal".  However, if you lookup the word convey, you'll see definitions like these:

- Transport or carry to a place.
- Make (an idea, impression, or feeling) known or understandable to someone.

Nowhere in any dictionary have I seen this mean "deal" or "administer".  What are we doing, making the enemies understand the damage they are being dealt?

In all seriousness, though, I am going to go with the definition of "to take X damage and divide and deal it out equally to a target over Y seconds".  However, I just want to be sure.

Comment: Sounds like someone who tried too hard to come up with a different verb and failed miserbly.

Comment: If you hit an enemy (or the training dummy) with a "conveys X damage over Y time" effect on your weapon, you'll see a status effect over the enemy whose icon is typically that of the weapon you used and that lasts for Y time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your theory on how this works is correct.

I tested out my weapons that "Conveyed x damage over y seconds" by hitting a monster and then backing up and watching their health bar.  The health bar went down without me touching the monster, and since I had not burned, froze, poisoned, or otherwise cast a spell to bring the monster's health down, I concluded that the "convey x damage..." deals that amount of damage over time to the monster.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, your last proposed definition is what I have observed. This can be best demonstrated on an enemy with lots of health (champion or boss level).

As an example, if you have a weapon that deals 200 physical damage over 5 seconds, and you strike said enemy, you should note a timer icon appear over the enemy's stat bar. The icon, as I recall, is one of the physical weapon types (maybe a mace? I forget), and the timer will start counting down from 5.

Icons like this will occasionally appear for your character down in the lower left hand portion of the screen (above the action bar). If you mouse over the icons, you'll get a tool-tip explaining what the icon means. I wish that you could do the same thing for the icons affecting enemies, since some of the icons seem a little cryptic.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between "Conveys X" and "Deals X" is subtle but important. In the dictionary sense, it means to transport.

An item property that Conveys X (damage or potential status effect, doesn't matter) means that if the property is on armor/jewelry, it will be passed along by any abilities that do % Weapon DPS or % Weapon Damage and strike multiple enemies.

If the property is on or socketed in a weapon, then it must be on the main hand to be passed along with a chain/splash/AOE ability. If it's on the offhand, it will still be used on the primary target when that weapon strikes but won't be considered otherwise as those type of abilities only use the main hand, which is why you always want hard damage mods in your main hand and socket booster properties in the offhand like % crit damage etc..

Properties that Deals X only apply to the primary target. Same for health steal, mana steal etc.. If it doesn't say "Conveys", it won't be passed to secondary targets.